# .htaccess conflict while removing extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

OK. So I'm currently making a website to show images. (Kinda like Imgur I guess), and the normal URL is /n?=image, now I have a rewrite to change that to /image, which works fine.

I also have a Privacy Policy, ToS and Contact pages which I would like to remove the extensions from (.php). The Privacy Policies page works fine, as that file is in a Directory called "policies". So it removes the .php extension without a hassle.

When I go to /contact however, it redirects it thinking it is an image. Is it possible to have the removal of the .php extension, as well as redirecting images at the same time? I had a search on here but couldn't find anything relating to this issue that helped.

```
# Snapr Rewrites
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?n=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).png$ index.php?n=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).png$

# Remove .PHP from URL's
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

#### EDIT:

Basically. I'm wanting to have:

`http://example.com/?n=image` turn into `http://example.com/image`

`http://example.com/contact.php` turn into `http://example.com/contact`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for existence of `.php` file before adding `.php` for a request and more importantly keep `.php` adding rule before other image rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# handle images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\.png)?$ index.php?n=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: (Won't let me accept this answer for another 4 minutes) Thank you! I didn't even think about checking for the existence of the .php file first. I had the .php before originally, but it didn't work so I was thinking it was an order issue. Thank you @anubhava!